# switch between different listener

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm using a gesture listener to monitor user's action, but when the app pops up the dialog, I don't know how to switch my gesture listener to dialog event and handle the event button (ok and cancel), can anyone give me a suggestion?

Pseudo code likes this

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements ConnectionEventListener{
        ......
        // when connection established,
        // pop a diaglog (android native diaglog with listview and its adapter) to ask user to select ok or cancel button
        @Override
        public void onUpdateAlert(final int event, final String message){
        }

        // gesture listener
        // if a dialog pops up, the pose can be used to select OK or cancel
        @Override
        public void onDetected(Hand pose){
        }
}
```

The problem I have is not the button listener. Actually, I have two listeners work at the same time, one for event monitor and another for pose monitor. When an event comes, the event will pop up a dialog to select "ok" or "cancel" . In the mean time, a pose listener still works. I'd like to know when this case happens, how can I use the pose listener to select "ok" or "cancel" while the diaglod pops up?

Comment: which dialog u used

Comment: Please explain via code and be more specific to make understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need something like this:

```
public static void showDialog(SomeActivity someActivity, final SomeCallback callBack {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(someActivity);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_buttons);

    // OK button ...
    Button dialogButtonOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            callBack.execute(true);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Cancel button ...
    Button buttonCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callBack.execute(false);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

we can call the showDialog from SomeActivity like this:

```
showDialog(this, new SomeCallback () {
    @Override
    public void execute(boolean status) {
        if (status) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

and the callback interface:

```
public interface SomeCallback {
    void execute(boolean status);
}
```

good luck

---

the pseudo code can be like:

```
boolean status = false;

@Override
public void onUpdateAlert(final int event, final String message){
    status = true;    
    // pop up the dialog
}

@Override
public void onDetected(Hand pose){
    if(status) {
            status = false;
            ...          
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The problem I have is not the button listener. I have two listeners work at the same time, one for event monitor and another for pose monitor. When an event comes, the event will pop up a dialog to select "ok" or "cancel" . In the mean time, a pose listener still works. I'd like to know when this case happens, how can I use the pose listener to select "ok" or "cancel" when the diaglod pops up?

Comment: we can check whether the dialog is popped up or not in the pose monitor, so we can do the logic there ?

Comment: not very clear. is it possible to have a pseudo code?

Comment: please see the pseudo code above this comments,  I couldn't write it here